# How to iterate over cfreturn serializeJson within a script tag in coldfusion

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, cfc

I am new to Coldfusion and trying to learn and develop an application.

I have a cfcomponent, which takes a start and end date and execute a query. The result of the query I serialize using the following

```
 <cfreturn serializeJSON(data=myloaddata,queryformat="struct") >
```

This works and the data is in this format.

```
[{"UTCTIME":"December, 15 2023 00:00:00","LOCALTIME":"December, 14 2023 19:00:00","UNIT_ID":1001,"LOAD_INT":null,"LOAD_INTTLQ":null,"Sample":2811,"SampleVal":2740},{"UTCTIME":"December, 22 2023 00:00:00","LOCALTIME":"December, 21 2023 19:00:00","UNIT_ID":1001,"LOAD_INT":null,"LOAD_INTTLQ":null,"Sample":2811,"SampleVal":2832}]
```

The issue I am facing is result is return to my $.get() call within my script tag.

```
<script>
$.get(`getMonthlyLoad.cfc?method=user.cfc&startDate=${range.start}&endDate=${range.end}`, function(data){
            console.log(data);
         });
 </script>
```

I would like to iterate over the result value in data to create html table, however when I iterate over data object it prints one character at a time.
data[0] will show '[', data[1] will show '{' .. etc
Basically printing character by character.

I don't understand why its not printing as an object since the result from the query is a json object. Any help would be great.

Comment: It's been serialized into a string, so you'll need to deserialize it in JS with `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Where would the JSON.parse() be called ? In the <cfreturn .. ?

Comment: In the javascript when you want to iterate over it. Parsing it in `<cfreturn>` (not that `JSON.parse()` would work in CF) would undo the `SerializeJSON()`

Comment: I tried `for(i in data){console.log(JSON.parse(data[i]))}` but getting an error.  VM3178:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (monthlyload.cfm:378:23)
    at c (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:27742)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:28487)
    at l (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:78789)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:81117)

Comment: I recommend that in your CF function that gets the data, you specify in the function declaration `returnformat="json"`.  ColdFusion will format the return results to JSON without having to specify serialization.  Then on the JS side, you wouldn't need to do the `JSON.parse` either. The results you are getting is JS thinking it's dealing with a string instead of an object.

Comment: @snackboy I did this change but i am getting the data in this format. `"COLUMNS":["Time","NOW","TEST","FROM","TO"` Which is still being iterated in JS as a string rather that a JSON Object

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot that CF has that format for query data. Typically what I do is loop over the query results in CF and build out the object as an array of structs and then return it back to JS. (If you'd like code on what I do, I am happy to share.) For now though, try putting the code back to how you had it, and do the `JSON.parse(data)` in your JS .get function.

Comment: @snackboy if you dont mind sharing, that would be great. I tried JSON.parse(data) in a for loop and results was throwing the error above... Unexpected end of JSON

Comment: I just posted an answer. Don't do the JSON.parse() in the loop, do it before the loop. As for what I do, I posted this a while ago: https://dev.to/snackcode/uncommon-practices-cfquery-to-json-2poh. It might help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256504/discussion-between-snackboy-and-amit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data on CF side is being serialized into a string, you would need to turn it back into an object on the JS side. In your JS code, try the following:

```
<script>
    $.get(`getMonthlyLoad.cfc? method=user.cfc&startDate=${range.start}&endDate=${range.end}`, 
    function(data){
        var myData = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(myData);
    });
</script>
```

I was able to take the data you posted to make sure the output was good:

```
<script>
        function doStuff() {
            var _d = '[{"UTCTIME":"December, 15 2023 00:00:00","LOCALTIME":"December, 14 2023 19:00:00","UNIT_ID":1001,"LOAD_INT":null,"LOAD_INTTLQ":null,"Sample":2811,"SampleVal":2740},{"UTCTIME":"December, 22 2023 00:00:00","LOCALTIME":"December, 21 2023 19:00:00","UNIT_ID":1001,"LOAD_INT":null,"LOAD_INTTLQ":null,"Sample":2811,"SampleVal":2832}]';
            var _md = JSON.parse(_d);
            console.log('json',_md);
        }
    
        doStuff();
</script>
```

Output was as expected:

```
[
    {
        "UTCTIME": "December, 15 2023 00:00:00",
        "LOCALTIME": "December, 14 2023 19:00:00",
        "UNIT_ID": 1001,
        "LOAD_INT": null,
        "LOAD_INTTLQ": null,
        "Sample": 2811,
        "SampleVal": 2740
    },
    {
        "UTCTIME": "December, 22 2023 00:00:00",
        "LOCALTIME": "December, 21 2023 19:00:00",
        "UNIT_ID": 1001,
        "LOAD_INT": null,
        "LOAD_INTTLQ": null,
        "Sample": 2811,
        "SampleVal": 2832
    }
]
```

Comment: This is still throwing an error for non-whitespace as above. My cfcomponent does a DB query and the results of the query I do `<cfreturn serializeJSON(data=getload,queryformat="struct") >' Is this causing the issue ? Not clear why it would though

Comment: If you console.log(data) on the JS side, what do you get?

Comment: I see why the JSON.parse is not working now. When I console log the data return from the cfcomponent, it include the following `<!-- Database Links -->` with the JSON data. Do you know what would be causing this ? `[{"UTCTIME":"December, 15 2023 00:00:00","LOCALTIME":"December, 14 2023 19:00:00","UNIT_ID":1001,"LOAD_INT":null,"LOAD_INTTLQ":null,"Sample":2811,"SampleVal":2740},{"UTCTIME":"December, 22 2023 00:00:00","LOCALTIME":"December, 21 2023 19:00:00","UNIT_ID":1001,"LOAD_INT":null,"LOAD_INTTLQ":null,"Sample":2811,"SampleVal":2832}] <!-- Database Links -->`

Comment: I removed it using data.replace() but would like to know where its going from

Comment: Can you post the entire CF function that's returning the data?

Comment: If your function isn't prepending and post pending that `<!--- Database Links --->`  you may want to check your application.cfc to see if that is doing something on the CF function returns.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but yest it seems on the application.cfc was appending the value, I think it was a misconfiguration. Thanks again !